# Updating a Salesforce record from Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, salesforce

I am trying to update a single field in a custom salesforce object from Google Apps Script.  The field is a checkbox.  Here is the apps script code

```
     try {
       var payload = Utilities.jsonStringify(
          {"update_GApps_Directory__c": 0
          }
        );
        var contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        var feedUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/GApps_User_Directory__c/" + userId
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feedUrl, {method: "PATCH",headers: {"Authorization": "OAuth " + accessToken}, payload: payload, contentType: contentType});
        var postResult = Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());
    } catch (err) {
        Logger.log("POST ERROR: " + err);
    }
```

The resulting request, modified to hide some stuff;

c/jim.xxxon@nexxxxxxxginc.com,%20%7Bheaders=%7BAuthorization=OAuth%2000D80xxxxxxxxxxxxBAJZRUEIeMrwFymv5_MAQfwerIlDuSd8oAFYuKyxxxxxxxxxrnnIowtwHozI%7D,%20payload=%7B%22update_GApps_Directory__c%22:0%7D,%20method=PATCH,%20contentType=application/json;%20charset=utf-8%7D">https://na8.salesforce.com/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/GApps_User_Directory_*c/jim.xxxon@nexxxxxxxginc.com,%20%7Bheaders=%7BAuthorization=OAuth%2000D80xxxxxxxxxxxxBAJZRUEIeMrwFymv5*_MAQfwerIlDuSd8oAFYuKyxxxxxxxxxrnnIowtwHozI%7D,%20payload=%7B%22update_GApps_Directory__c%22:0%7D,%20method=PATCH,%20contentType=application/json;%20charset=utf-8%7D

and the error;

Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: method

which I am assuming means it does not like Patch as the method.  the object, GApps_User_Directory__c, has an unique external id which is an email address and this record does exist.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13294/patch-request-using-apex-httprequest  I had to use the post method and "override" the method to patch in the feed url by adding "?_HttpMethod=PATCH" to the end of it.